# Question on statement of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $\vert\langle x,y \rangle \vert \leq \Vert x \Vert \cdot \Vert y \Vert$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, notation

Denoting the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality as [Wikipedia does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Statement_of_the_inequality), 
$$\vert\langle x,y \rangle \vert \leq \Vert x \Vert \cdot \Vert y \Vert$$
and noting that 
$$\vert\langle x,y \rangle \vert = \Vert x\cdot y \Vert$$
Which gives the version of Cauchy-Schwarz that I'm used to seeing, my question is why does the Wikipedia page remove the norm notation on the left and leave it on the right. That is, why not write:
$$ \tag{3}
\vert\langle x,y \rangle \vert \leq \vert x  \vert \cdot \vert y  \vert$$
Is it just because writing it as $(3)$ would not be meaningful? Or is there actually a problem with taking the square root of $\Vert x \Vert$, since the square root gives us
$$
\sum x_i^2
$$
Which does not actually equal $x$, but instead it's magnitude?

Thanks

Edit: Also, since I am on the topic, why is  the left side in $\vert\cdot \vert$ notation? The left side is the sum of positive terms, and must be positive, at least if we are in $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean norm. I'm assuming they have the notation as such for generality (that is, in spaces besides $\mathbb{R}$ or with other norms, perhaps something such that the left side is not necessarily positive?) **Nevermind** This is answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/133951/265678), and also in a comment now

Comment: The left side is the absolute value of a scalar; the right is the product of two vector norms.

Comment: The left side is not always positive. For instance $(1,1) \cdot (1,-2)=1-2=-1$. But the inequality still holds (here it reads $1 \leq \sqrt{10}$).

Comment: It is important to note that this inequality is valid for all spaces provided with a inner product ($R^{n}$  for example).  See too the Hölder inequality, it is a generalization of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\langle x,y \rangle$ is a real number, so $\lvert \cdot \rvert$ is used, being the ordinary absolute value on $\mathbb{R}$. Contrast with $x,y$, which are vectors.

Regarding your second question, $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ is bilinear (or sesquilinear), so it is certainly not always positive! $\langle x , -y \rangle = -\langle x,y\rangle $, and both cannot be positive!

Comment: Thank you very much, and sorry for the low-level question.